# Is there a way to make a property for a vcxproj in the Property Pages not be bolded using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, vcxproj

I know that when a property appears bold in Property Pages it indicates that it has been modified.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/675f1588.aspx

I have an API that we ship samples with, and I want all of the settings across all of them to be consistent and the same.

Unfortunately, some sample vcxprojs appear to have the right setting and are not bolded, while others somehow had a wrong setting and after changing it to the right one, it's obviously still bold.

I want all of the samples Property Pages to be consistent across all of the samples, even the bolding of text. I realize this is really just an OCD cosmetic type of an issue, and there is no technical problem behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .vcxproj file is just an XML file. I'm assuming that bold means that there is a setting specified in the file, even if it's the default.

So: edit the file in a normal text editor. *Remove* the setting, so that it uses the default value, and so that it no longer appears in bold in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can it cause unexpected results if in future MSVS versions defaults will be changed?

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I kept trying to delete the value in Visual Studio itself, saving it, coming back in and then it would be blank like I left it and not the default. I wish there was a way to do it in the GUI. Revert to Default Value or some crap like that. There is no reason they can't add that.

Comment: The reason they don't do that, is that every feature starts with -100 points,  just for being a new feature, and basically they don't think there is enough demand for it.

Comment: Right, because I and others love slogging through XML files ;-). Whatever. I'm cleaning it all up and becoming more versed in the vcxproj files in the process.